# Unable to read database values with my combobox in C#

Tags: c#, ms-access, combobox, datareader

I am having the following problem which I can't seem to solve. With a combobox, that lists all database table field names I want to readout the values that are selected in the combobox and display them in a textbox. Example: when I choose the combobox value Rent, the reader should get the values related to the Rent field name.

First I try'd to add all the database field names manually to my combobox, so in the items->collection I just manually typed all the field names.

Then I used this code to output the selected field names values:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string FieldName = (string)comboBox1.SelectedItem;
    textBox15.Text = FieldName;

    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
        command.Connection = connection;
        string query = "select [" + comboBox1.Text + "] from Expenses where Month='January'";

        command.CommandText = query;
        OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();  

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            textBox14.Text = (reader[comboBox1.Text].ToString());
        }

        connection.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error" + ex);
    }
}
```

This actually worked. Though then I wanted to make my combobox values a bit more flexible by reading all the field names and then put them automatically in the combobox (so now the user could also add field names), I removed the manually typed field names in the collection of the combobox.

The automatic adding of field names is done with this code:

```
OleDbCommand command2 = new OleDbCommand();
command2.Connection = connection;
string query2 = "select * from Expenses where Month='January'";
command2.CommandText = query2;
OleDbDataReader reader2 = command2.ExecuteReader();              

while (reader2.Read())
{
    for (int i = 0; i < reader2.FieldCount; i++)
    {
         comboBox1.Items.Add(reader2.GetName(i));                       
    }
}
connection.Close();
```

Using this way to add my field names to the combobox works excellent, but for some reason the first piece of code (displaying the field name values in a textbox) doesn't work anymore when this was changed.. 
The error I am getting now is: No value given for one or more required parameters... on line 642 which is the line of: `OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();`

Anyone knows what the reason is of the function not working anymore?

Comment: What are the values of the combobox?

Comment: What's the value of the `query` variable before the error?

Comment: Not sure I exactly know what you mean but the query variable depends on which combobox value is selected. So when i select the combobox value Rent then the query value is: select [Rent] from Expenses where Month='January'.  The value of the comboBox.text is queal to the field name (just the word Rent that is).

Comment: Alright I found the problem. Bit ashamed to tell it, but I swapped the comboboxes names in the initialize process, this caused my table 1 values to be displayed in combobox 2 and my table 2 values in combobox 1, so the reader was looking for values in the wrong table's;). Thank you anyway for the effort.